# Given that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$.Show that:$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\ge 64$

Tags: inequality, tangent-line-method

Given that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$ show that:$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\ge 64$$
My attempt: First I tried expanding the LHS getting that$$abc+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c \ge 63$$
I applied Cauchy-Schwarz on $(a+b+c)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})$ getting that $a+b+c\ge9$.

Then I also tried to manipulate the first condition and got $abc=ab+bc+ca$, then I applied AM-GM on $a+b+c$ getting the following$$a+b+c\ge3\sqrt[3]{abc}$$
Finally I substituted $ab+bc+ca=abc$ in my initial expression, getting:$$2abc+(a+b+c)\ge63$$The last thing I tought about was that I have both $a+b+c\ge9$ and $a+b+c\ge3\sqrt[3]{abc}$ so if I somehow related them I would have $\sqrt[3]{abc} \ge 3 \rightarrow abc\ge27$ and with this conditions the problem would follow by summing, but the direction of the inequality is not allowing me to do as intended...

I'm stuck here, have tried lot of other things but nothing really worked, also partial help is appreciated!

Comment: I haven't tried this I admit .... but my instant thought is, since we 'know' (please note the apostrophæ!) that it attains its minimum value at a=b=c=3, could we not _hypothesise_ that it's 3, plug in 3+δ, 3+ε, & 3+ζ, & show that any increase in some measure of the size of δ, ε & ζ causes an increase in the product under the constraint? As I said - just my instantaneous thought on seeing the question!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey One could take the second partial derivative (since the expression is symetric you can take it with respect to any variable) and see that the function $f(a,b,c)=(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$ is convex since it's second derivative is equal to zero, given this we basically done what you suggested to (i.e. any increment in a,b,c gives us an increment in f(a,b,c)) but the thing is, you'd still have to formally prove that a=b=c=3 it's the minimal value of the funcion which really doesn't seem easy to me (in one of the answers they actually proved that 3 is the minimal value, you can look it up)

Comment: @ Spasoje Durovic -- So you can without too much difficulty prove the way said maybe you could? ... _assuming_ that the minimum is at a=b=c=3 ... but then the big stumbilngblock is proving that the minimum _is_ at that? It's funny how _so often_ the stumbilngblock of a proof is the _seemingly_ most trivial part of it!

Comment: But do you really _need_ to prove that, logically to prove this theorem _as it stands_? ... as you can just _calculate_ that at a=b=c=3 the product in the theorem is 64 -- so if you prove that any departure (satisfying the constraint) from that point can only _increase_ that product, surely then you've proven the theorem _as it stands_? Although I see that if you only have _convexity, then_ you would also need to prove that the minimum is at that particular point.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey I think a formal proof of a=b=c=3 being the minimal value is needed but if you could somehow show that by substituting $3+\alpha$ or $3-\alpha$ leads to an increase you would be done, long story short I think that this sort of approach altought theoretically exhaustive would be painful to face, in my humble opinion it would be hopeless but I'd be more than happy to be proven wrong :) I enjoy looking at different perspectives regarding a problem

Comment: And it looks promising on the face of it! Maybe what you've said then explains why none of the people here have done it that way!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By the super-additivity of the geometric mean / convexity of $\log(e^x+1)$
$$ (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \geq (1+\sqrt[3]{abc})^3 $$
and by the GM-HM inequality
$$ \sqrt[3]{abc} \geq \frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}=3.$$

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I do not see anything wrong with this approach, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I am assuming $a,b,c > 0$, of course.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter's arithmetic is so bad that they want you explain that $4^3 = 64$ $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: No, the downvoter did not like super havy stuff for such elementary inequality.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm convinced that there are users who stays here on MSE only to downvote, probably to give vent to frustration in the real world!

Comment: @greedoid Nothing personal with the comment, I was only joking of course.

Comment: @greedoid I don't thing that also advanced methods are bad, they are stimulating to learn something new!

Comment: @gimusi Non taken........

Comment: I could end my proof with that application of the GM-HM isn't it?, so dumb of me not thinking about HM given that condition I had...!

Comment: @gimusi: if your theory is right, the downvoter should have provided an alternative answer rather than downvoting Jack.

Comment: @RobArthan Not a theory but only a joke! Bye :)

Comment: @RobArthan It did.....

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio -- heed Rob Arthan ... _and_ me. _Every_ web forum is a _trollpit_ ... including the relatively respectable ones (and even the _absolutely_ respectable ones - whichever they might be). _Do not regard_ downvotes ... _ever_ on _any_ forum.

Answer (score 13):

I think you mean $$a,b,c>0$$ in this case we have
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}$$ so $$a+b+c\geq 9$$ and we get also $$\frac{bc+ac+ab}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$$ so $$abc\geq 27$$  and $$ab+ac+bc\geq 27$$ putting things together we have
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=abc+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c+1\geq 27+27+10=64$$

Comment: Welcome back Dr. Graubner!

Comment: Yeah, OP forgot to mention that $a,b,c$ have to be positive, I forgot to add that I had noticed that

Comment: Thanks, i'm also glad to see you!

Answer (score 8):

Since $ab+bc+ca= abc$ and $$ab+bc+ca\geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}\implies abc\geq 27$$
Now $$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=2abc+a+b+c+1\geq 55+3\sqrt[3]{27} = 64$$

Comment: Yup, that first passage was the one I didn't see, I'm actually terrible at AM-GM!...

Comment: Yeah, I've started working on inequalities about a week ago, hope I'll get better soon! cheers (nice to see you're from the Balkans too :P)

Comment: Actualy I'm not.

Comment: My bad! I supposed it since you used Cyrillic

Comment: How did you get $ab+bc+ca\geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}\implies abc\geq 27$ @Aqua

Comment: Use first equation @SomeGuy

Answer (score 2):

For positive variables we need to prove that
$$\ln\left((1+a)(1+b)(1+c)\right)\geq\ln64$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(\ln(1+a)-2\ln2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln(1+a)-2\ln2+\frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)\geq0,$$
which is true because
$$f(a)=\ln(1+a)-2\ln2+\frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\geq0$$ for all $a>0$.

Indeed, $$f'(a)=\frac{(a-3)(4a+3)}{4a^2(a+1)},$$ which gives $a_{min}=3$ and since $f(3)=0$, we are done!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got the first expression?

Comment: @YiFan presumably by taking the $\ln(\bullet)$ of both sides using the fact that $\ln$ increases monotonically hence preserving the inequality. Then there is a splitting the of the $\ln(64)$ term into three equal parts to get it into the cyclic sum, those being $\ln(64)/3 = \ln(4) = 2 \ln(2).$

Comment: @CRDrost Of course. Thanks for the help!