# Let $a,b,c>0$ with$ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = 1$. Prove that $(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1) \geq 64$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ with$ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = 1$. Prove that
$(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1) \geq 64$

Ohk so we are given that $abc=a+b+c$ with that now the inequality becomes $2abc+(a+b+c)+1 \geq 64$

How do i proceed from here?

Comment: The first condition gives you $ab+bc+ca=abc$ not $abc=a+b+c$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3026163/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a+1=1+\frac ab+\frac ac+1$$
etc. Multiply this with the similar expressions for $b+1$ and $c+1$ and use
AM/GM.

Comment: Actually i am a beginner to olympiad number theory and inequalities. Could you please explain further?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means for AM/GM. It is one of the cornerstones of inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=\frac 1a,\,y=\frac 1b,\,z=\frac 1z$ then $x+y+z=1.$ Inequality become
$$\left(\frac 1x+1\right)\left(\frac 1y+1\right)\left(\frac 1z+1\right)\geqslant 64,$$
or
$$\left (\frac{2x+y+z}{x} \right)\left (\frac{2y+z+x}{y} \right)\left (\frac{2z+x+y}{z} \right) \geqslant 64,$$
or
$$(2x+y+z)(2z+x+y)(2z+x+y) \geqslant 64. \quad (1)$$
Suppose $z=\min\{x,y,z\}.$ We can write $(1)$ become
$$2(x+y+8z)(x-y)^2+(9x+9y+2z)(x-z)(y-z) \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true. We are done.

Comment: Interesting substitution. Nice $+1$.

Comment: How is that different from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591808/42969) to the possible duplicate target?

Comment: @MartinR I did not follow Sai Teja idea. I just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Now, after homogenization we need to prove that:
$$2(ab+ac+bc)+\frac{(a+b+c)abc}{ab+ac+bc}\geq\frac{63a^2b^2c^2}{(ab+ac+bc)^2}$$ or
$$2(ab+ac+bc)^3+(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)abc\geq63a^2b^2c^2,$$ which is obvious by AM-GM:
$$2(ab+ac+bc)^3+(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)abc\geq$$
$$\geq2\left(3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}\right)^3+abc\cdot3\sqrt[3]{abc}\cdot3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=63a^2b^2c^2,$$